# Querydsl to read the database tables and generate the Java classes

Tags: java, eclipse, querydsl

I use mySql and Eclpse, and I need to invoke Querydsl to read the database tables and generate the Java classes. That's my code, but it doesn't work (no errors, but the new classes do not appear). I think the problem is the path to the target folder... (C:\workspace\demo\src\com\myproject\domain)

`java.sql.Connection conn = ...;
       MetaDataExporter exporter = new MetaDataExporter();
       exporter.setPackageName("com.myproject.domain");

       exporter.setTargetFolder(new File("scr")); 
       exporter.export(connection.getMetaData());`

Comment: the problem was solved: exporter.setTargetFolder(new File("C:/workspace/demo/src"));